# highlight duplicate Value in Open Office org Calc

Tags: duplicates, openoffice.org, openoffice-calc

I am using **`OPEN OFFICE ORG CALC`**.

**I can't use `MSOFFICE`**

How can i **highlight Duplicate** value in a `Column` ?

I am in real need. Did my part of homework **[LINK 1](http://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=5379), [Link 2](http://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/How_Tos/Removing_Duplicate_Rows)**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One simple way is to use **countif**. See image. Use the **`$`** signs to **`Fix`** the search range. The next step could be to us this in a conditional format formula.

[image]

[image]

Maybe not as nice (and smooth) as in Excel, but it highlights, duplicates.
Put the formula in e.g. **`Cell A1`**, then use the **format paintbrush** to copy the format down.

Comment: If this doesn't work for text with brackets, make sure `Menu Tools > Options > OpenOffice.org Calc > Calculate
Enable regular expressions in formulas` is unchecked.